# running elixir poison commands in iex

Tags: json, elixir, elixir-iex, elixir-poison

I am a greenhorn in `elixir` and want to test the `Poison` functions from `iex`

https://hexdocs.pm/poison/1.3.1/#functions_details

```
iex> Poison.decode("[1,2,3]")
```

When I run this command I am getting the error below.

```
iex(1)> Poison.decode("[1,2,3]")
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Poison.decode/1 is undefined (module Poison is not available)
    Poison.decode("[1,2,3]")
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `mix` project (created by `mix new project_name` or `mix phx.new project_name`), run `iex -S mix` to load dependencies into your `iex` console. Make sure you are in the projects directory.
If you don't have such project, create it.

Make sure the required packages are listed in `mix.exs`:

```
defp deps do
  [
     {:poison, "~> 4.0"}
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just start `iex` it has no extra code loaded. Assuming `poison` is added as a dependency in your `mix.exs` you can start `iex` in the context of your application by running:

```
iex -S mix
```

You can also do:

```
iex -S mix run --no-start
```

In this case it will only load the code, but not start your supervision tree.